# Windows text file viewer that works on Linux text files

Tags: linux, windows, notepad, ascii

Is there a way under Windows to view ASCII files that have the Linux-style newline sequence of a single ASCII LF character? Something like like a `gedit` for Windows.

I need to to this in Windows 8.1 on VirtualBox inside of Linux.

I am aware of `todos` and `fromdos` but it's not convenient to do conversions.

Comment: Notepad++ or SublimeText. Any decent Windows text editor will handle UNIX style text files

Comment: Pretty much anything that's *not* `notepad.exe` will render LF correctly...even on Windows!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ultimate built-in solution: WordPad. It's true! :)

For an optimal visual experience, go to the “View” ribbon and select “Word wrap” → “No wrap” (or “Wrap to window”, if that’s your thing). That does away with the page-styled view.

Comment: On my Windows 7 machine, Wordpad views such files fine, but I can find no option which will save text files edited with same to the Linux newline format.  Word is capable of doing this, however.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with you here. I want WordPad to be good, but for some reason, it is strictly tied to paper/page sizes as dictated by a printer? 

If you want or need something that can gracefully handle very long lines, you will need a third party solution (gedit for windows, sublime text, notepad++, etc)

Answer (score 2):

gedit for windows??... how about [gedit for windows](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/gedit/) ;)

I'm sat with a linux dev in my office right now who said that this should handle what you need ti to quite happily.

Answer (score 1):

Anything other than Notepad. (no joke)

If you don't want to install anything, WordPad will work.  My personal favorite is [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html).

Comment: Try Notepad++. It has way more features than Notepad, like syntax colouring for code, column select, multiple file tabs and more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.6.html). 
It will display the file newline format at the bottom right of status bar.

To show the newline characters explicitly, go to `View -> Show Symbol` and tick on the `Show End of Line` option.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can also change file ending on the fly, as needed.